# how do i pause a sound / song using python?

Tags: python, background-music

I would like to pause the music / audio of chrome. for example when I receive a specific input the audio of a video stops and then restarts when it receives a specific input, what should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called dbus, and there is even a python library for it.

You will first have to find the name of the media player using the following code.

```py
import dbus

for service in dbus.SessionBus().list_names():
    if ".Media" in service:
        print(service)
```

You will get a list something like this

```
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance1234
...
```

In the things printed, find the one that looks to be your browser.

Then the easiest way to run this command is just using subprocess.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    [
        "dbus-send",
        "--print-reply",
        "--dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance1234",
        "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
        "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause",
    ],
)
```

After that, it should pause or play the song.

Note: You don't just have to do `PlayPause`, there is also `Previous` and `Next` and `Pause`.

If you want to use input, you can do something like this

```py
import subprocess


def pause_play():
    subprocess.run(
        [
            "dbus-send",
            "--print-reply",
            "--dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance63145",
            "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
            "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause",
        ],
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        command = input("Enter a command: ")
        if command == "p":
            pause_play()
```

Comment: I don't find dbus on windows 10, solution?

Comment: @francescodiploma You can make a dbus server, here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390064/use-dbus-to-just-send-a-message-in-python

Comment: There are more options such as: next, previous, stop, seek, setposition etc. MediaPlayer2.Player manual here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/2.2/Player_Interface.html

Comment: @zeroalpha thank you for the source. Good addition.